# Multithreaded console output?

Tags: multithreading, go

If I have multiple go-routines going and 2 or more of them decide they need to print something out, is it possible for them to interrupt each other?

For example:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    go print()
    print()
}

func print() {
    for true {
        fmt.Print("ABCDEF")
    }
}
```

Is it possible for one go-routine to start printing (`AB`) and another go-routine interrupting (`ABABCDEF`) and the original finishing (`ABABCDEFCDEF`)?

I've tried running it myself and checking the output and it *looks* good, but how can I be sure?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it's possible, though you won't see any with GOMAXPROCS=1. They will show up when running with more goroutines, larger lines, and more threads. Even more so when writing to stderr, which is unbuffered, since the stdout buffer accepts the short writes fast enough to help prevent interleaving.

This is why the Logger in the "log" package has an internal mutex and buffer, to properly serialize the calls.

Comment: So, to be crystal clear, using the log package means threads can never interrupt each other?

Comment: @CoreyOgburn: yes, as long as you are only writing with a single Logger, and not from anywhere else (e.g. any fmt.Printfs might overlap with log lines)