# Issue with channel / go routine synchronization in Go

Tags: go

Here is a small example program with the basic architecture/flow that I am trying to get working.  How do I get all the numbers and "end" messages to print out?  I have tried putting close statements here and there, but it either doesn't work, or I get panics about trying to close an already closed channel...

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    d := make(chan uint)

    go bar(d)

    c1 := make(chan uint)
    c2 := make(chan uint)
    c3 := make(chan uint)

    go foo(c1, d)
    go foo(c2, d)
    go foo(c3, d)

    c1 <- 1
    c2 <- 2
    c3 <- 3

    c1 <- 4
    c2 <- 5
    c3 <- 6

    c1 <- 7
    c2 <- 8
    c3 <- 9
}

func foo(c chan uint, d chan uint) {
    fmt.Println("foo start")

    for stuff := range c {
        time.Sleep(1)
        d <- stuff * 2
    }

    fmt.Println("foo end")
}

func bar(d chan uint) {
    fmt.Println("bar start")

    for stuff := range d {
        fmt.Printf("bar received %d\n", stuff)
    }

    fmt.Println("bar end")
}
```

The output I am getting looks like this.  Notice the last set of numbers and the "end" outputs are missing.

```
foo start
bar start
foo start
foo start
bar received 6
bar received 2
bar received 4
bar received 12
bar received 8
bar received 10
```

In my actual program, each "foo" function is doing filtering and a bunch of heavy string regexp stuff.  And I need the "bar" function, because it has the job of reordering based on a timestamp, and serializing printing, so output doesn't get interlaced.

Comment: Not quite answer worthy, but [in a question I asked about console interlacing](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31734215/multithreaded-console-output) I was told that using the `log` import would prevent it.

Comment: @CoreyOgburn that won't help when the problem here is that `main` doesn't wait for the goroutines to run (so output doesn't happen at all, interleaved/interlaced or not)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your program is exiting before all goroutines are done. You need to wait for both the `foo` and `bar` goroutines to finish before returning from `main`.

The usual way of doing this is by using a `sync.WaitGroup`, but since `main` isn't the producer for the `d` channel, you will have to ensure that all sends on that channel are finished before closing that with a second WaitGroup (or equivalent).

```
var (
    fooWG sync.WaitGroup
    barWG sync.WaitGroup
)

func main() {
    d := make(chan uint)

    barWG.Add(1)
    go bar(d)

    c1 := make(chan uint)
    c2 := make(chan uint)
    c3 := make(chan uint)

    fooWG.Add(3)
    go foo(c1, d)
    go foo(c2, d)
    go foo(c3, d)

    c1 <- 1
    c2 <- 2
    c3 <- 3

    c1 <- 4
    c2 <- 5
    c3 <- 6

    c1 <- 7
    c2 <- 8
    c3 <- 9

    // close the channels so the foo goroutines can exit
    close(c1)
    close(c2)
    close(c3)
    fooWG.Wait()

    // all foo are done, so it's safe to close d and wait for bar
    close(d)
    barWG.Wait()
}

func foo(c chan uint, d chan uint) {
    defer fooWG.Done()
    fmt.Println("foo start")

    for stuff := range c {
        time.Sleep(1)
        d <- stuff * 2
    }

    fmt.Println("foo end")
}

func bar(d chan uint) {
    defer barWG.Done()
    fmt.Println("bar start")

    for stuff := range d {
        fmt.Printf("bar received %d\n", stuff)
    }

    fmt.Println("bar end")
}
```

Comment: +1. You can also read this good article about this matter: http://nathanleclaire.com/blog/2014/02/15/how-to-wait-for-all-goroutines-to-finish-executing-before-continuing/

Comment: Awesome!  Thanks so much for the solution Jim, and the article pointer Elwinar.

Answer (score 1):

JimB's answer definitely works, but it's adding more complexity than is actually needed in the code.  A simple complete channel would suffice to synchronize this code though completion.

Also, with channel synchronization, the `time.Sleep(1)` command is no longer needed for functionality:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    d := make(chan uint)
    complete := make(chan bool)
    go bar(d, complete)

    c1 := make(chan uint)
    c2 := make(chan uint)
    c3 := make(chan uint)

    go foo(c1, d)
    go foo(c2, d)
    go foo(c3, d)

    c1 <- 1
    c2 <- 2
    c3 <- 3

    c1 <- 4
    c2 <- 5
    c3 <- 6

    c1 <- 7
    c2 <- 8
    c3 <- 9

    //If you know the number of inputs, count them to ensure completion
    for i:=0; i < 9; i++{
        <-complete
    }

    //Clean up after yourself, to keep away the memory leaks
    close(c1)
    close(c2)
    close(c3)
    close(d)

    //Verify bar is done and closed correctly
    <-complete
    close(complete)
}

func foo(c chan uint, d chan uint) {
    fmt.Println("foo start")

    for stuff := range c {
        time.Sleep(1)      //Not needed for the program to function
        d <- stuff * 2
    }

    fmt.Println("foo end")
}

func bar(d chan uint, cmp chan bool) {
    fmt.Println("bar start")

    for stuff := range d {
        fmt.Printf("bar received %d\n", stuff)
        cmp <- true
    }

    fmt.Println("bar end")

    //verify that cmp can be closed (all output is done, and d is closed)
    cmp <- true
}
```